# How to generate random code and check whether it exist in database or not

Tags: java

I try to generate random code name as licenseKey and check whether it is exist in database or not. If not exist, then display in my jsp page, if exist, continue generating the random code. I got the error "java.lang.StackOverflowError". How to solve this? Below is my code :

```
package com.raydar.hospital;
import com.raydar.hospital.DB_Connection;
import java.sql.*;

public class RandomCodeGenerator {


String licenseKey = "";

int noOfCAPSAlpha = 4;
int noOfDigits = 4;
int minLen = 8;
int maxLen = 8;

char[] code = RandomCode.generateCode(minLen, maxLen, noOfCAPSAlpha, noOfDigits);


public RandomCodeGenerator(){
}


public String getOutputCode() throws Exception{

    String result ="";

    result = isLicenseKeyExist();
    System.out.println("4 + " +result);

    if (result=="false"){

        System.out.println("1 + " +new String(code));

        licenseKey = new String(code);
    }

    else if (result=="true"){

            System.out.println("2 + " +new String(code));

            licenseKey = new String(code);

                isLicenseKeyExist ();         
        }           

    return licenseKey;
}



private String isLicenseKeyExist () throws Exception{
    String code = "";
    code = getOutputCode();

    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String result="";
    System.out.println("3 + " +code);

    try{
    DB_Connection connect = new DB_Connection();

    connection = connect.getDBConnection();
    statement = connection.createStatement();
    rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT licenseKey FROM hospital WHERE licenseKey = '" +code+ "'");
    if (rs.next()){    

    result = "true";

    }

    else{

        result = "false";

    }

    }catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("Error retrieving data! "+e);

}

    return result;

}
```

}

Comment: Not sure for other but you should not compare String with `==` return unexpected result instead use `String.equals()` method see [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java). Moreover you should use `Prepared Statement` to avoid `SQL Injection` See [Avoiding SQL injection in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391720/avoiding-sql-injection-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this.  Remove the field called `code` from your class, and its initialiser, and put the call to `RandomCode.generateCode` inside your `getOutputCode` method like this.  The reason is that you'll have to call it repeatedly if your code is already in the database.

```
public String getOutputCode() throws SQLException {
    String code;
    do {
        code = new String(RandomCode.generateCode(minLen, maxLen, noOfCAPSAlpha, noOfDigits));
    }
    while(licenceKeyExists(code));
    return code;
}
private boolean licenceKeyExists(String code) throws SQLException {
    try{
        DB_Connection connect = new DB_Connection();
        connection = connect.getDBConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT licenseKey FROM hospital WHERE licenseKey = '" +code+ "'");
        return rs.next();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException ignored){}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @David Wallace. is this code will continue generating another code if already exist in my database?

Comment: Yeah, that's what the do-while loop is for.

Comment: thanks @David Wallace. the boolean method should return true or false? sorry for my silly question :D

Comment: Yeah, a "boolean" is something that can either be true or false.  It's better to use these than to use Strings, if the only values that you're likely to get are "true" and "false".

Comment: so in this method i tried using return true or return false, is it both also can? because i still can get my output code

Comment: i meant this method i should return it as true or false @David Wallace

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your earlier comment means; but because `rs.next()` returns true or false, the line `return rs.next();` will return whichever is appropriate.

Comment: because i got error licenceKeyExists(String code) must return a result of type boolean @David Wallace. so i must return true or false is it?

Comment: Really?  Are you sure you pasted it exactly as I wrote it?  Look, I have to go offline now for a few hours, but I will help you with this later.  Or maybe someone else will.

Comment: yes @David Wallace, the return must be outside the try/catch. i tried put return rs.next(); outside the try/catch only then got no error.

Comment: Oh, so you've got another `catch` in there, before the `finally`?  OK, fair call.  I will fix up my answer, but I will show it throwing the `SQLException` on, rather than catching it, because I don't want to cloud the answer with error handling.

Answer (score 3):

You create a recursive loop where isLicenseKeyExist() calls getOutputCode(), but then getOutputCode() calls isLicenseKeyExist(). So eventually you run out of stack space, and get this exception.

Here,

```
public String getOutputCode() throws Exception{
    String result ="";
    result = isLicenseKeyExist();
   ...
```

}

```
private String isLicenseKeyExist () throws Exception{
    String code = "";
    code = getOutputCode();
...
}
```

Comment: but i want to call that method. so how to solve this?

Comment: @WhoAmI but i want to get the value of licenseKey in getOutputCode() into my isLicenseKeyExist (). how?

Comment: You should probably pass the code from `getOutputCode` to `isLicenceKeyExist` as a parameter, rather than trying to regenerate it inside `isLicenceKeyExist`.

Answer (score 0):

> @aween - @captureSteve has answered the first part of the question .
>   So, straight to  "I wan't to call this function" comment.  See, if I
>   understand your question correctly, you want to generate a key, and
>   check if it is available in the DB using isLicenseKeyExist() . In such
>   case, why don't you create the key first, then pass it to the
>   isLicenseKeyExist(). Then this function will return true/false based
>   on which you can decide what to do.

Comment: thanks. already change my code. in my if else statement, if result=="true", how to make sure it continue generating the code until no longer exist in database?

Comment: @aween - You could use a while loop. Check David Wallace's answer